# Is there a way of shortening my code?

Tags: c#, console

new C#er here. I'm making a text based adventure through a console app. I made a map command where when you type "map" it shows you a map with an X indicating your current location. Int variables xCoordinate and yCoordinate are used to represent character location on the map and change by 1 whenever you type "go north" or "go south" etc. The map is 13x10, so there are 130 possible places for your character to be. I made 130 different if statements and it works just fine. My question is if there is a more efficient/easier way of doing this. Here is what my code looks like:

```
    public static void Map()

    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + xCoordinate + ", " + yCoordinate);
        Console.WriteLine("\nTowns are represented by a \"T\". Current location is shown as an \"X\".\n");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
        if ((xCoordinate == -7) && (yCoordinate == -4))
        {
            Console.Write("[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][T][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] 5\n");
            Console.Write("[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] 4\n");
            Console.Write("[ ][ ][ ][ ][T][ ][ ][ ][ ][T][ ][ ][ ] 3\n");
            Console.Write("[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] 2\n");
            Console.Write("[ ][ ][T][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] 1\n");
            Console.Write("[T][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][T][ ][ ][ ][T][ ] 0\n");
            Console.Write("[ ][ ][ ][ ][T][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]-1\n");
            Console.Write("[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]-2\n");
            Console.Write("[ ][ ][T][ ][ ][ ][T][ ][ ][ ][T][ ][ ]-3\n");
            Console.Write("[X][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]-4\n");
            Console.Write("-7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5\n\n");
        }
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
  }
```

Again, I have the map typed out 130 times in 130 different if statements, each time the X is somewhere else. I would think there would be a better way to do this, but I have no idea.

Comment: This question is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: +1 for the persistance of writing that 130 times *before* thinking "There must be a better way" :-|

Comment: I made 130 different if statements ..hats off .. you hv a real dedication

Comment: Is it wrong that I want to see the entire 130 if loops?

Comment: @glosrob LOL, me too!

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/110562935/TextRPGTitle.cs
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/110562935/GlobalClass.cs

There is my source code if you want to look at it. It actually didn't take that long. It was a lot of copy pastas.

Comment: @JaredPrice fair play to you :) and well done for recognising there must be a better way - the solution below is good, you should use it and try apply to other places in your code. You don't ask, you don't get better. Good luck with the rest!

Comment: Something you'll learn as you continue to program is that any time you duplicate code even once, you're probably doing something wrong. This is often called the DRY Principle: Don't Repeat Yourself. Duplicating code 130 times is a pretty strong sign that there's an easier way. The next step in your programming education should be to learn about the difference between *representation* and *display*. What you want is a *data structure* that represents the state of the game, and then *display logic* that puts it on the screen.

Comment: Thanks glosrob! That will probably cut my code from nearly 10,000 lines of code to less than 1,000. I just wish I would have asked before I went nuts lol.

Comment: This might get you started: https://gist.github.com/jasonsperske/5163529 (it is by no means perfect)

Comment: Wow Jason, that's quite a bit of effort you put in to help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You should read and learn about loops like [for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx).

Something along lines

```
for(var xCoordinate  = -10; xCoordinate  <=10; xCoordinate ++)
{
   for(var yCoordinate = 5; yCoordinate >= 5; yCoordinate --)
   {
      if (xCoordinate  == ... && yCoordinate == ..)
      { 
         Console.Write("[X]");
      }
      else
      { 
         Console.Write("[ ]");
      }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void Map()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + xCoordinate + ", " + yCoordinate);
        Console.WriteLine("\nTowns are represented by a \"T\". Current location is shown as an \"X\".\n");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;

        for (int y = 5; y >= -4; y--)
        {
            for (int x = -7; x <= 5; x++)
            {
                Console.Write(yCoordinate == y && xCoordinate == x ? "[X]" : "[ ]");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" {0}", y);
        }
        Console.Write("-7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5\n\n");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
```

Comment: What about the `T`'s in the original?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jasonsperske/5163529, because I obsessively can't help myself :P